# Передать имя переменной в функцию

Tags: c++, c

Допустим у меня есть следующий `#define :`

```
#define _NAME_OF_ARG(ARG) #ARG
```

Примеры использования:

```
int x = 0;
std::cout << _NAME_OF_ARG(x);

output : x

int a[10] = {0};
std::cout << _NAME_OF_ARG(a[1]);

output : a[1]
```

Грубо говоря он выводит название переменной.
А например как мне выводить название переменной из следующей функции:

```
void something(int n, ...){
    int *point = &n;
    point--;
    while (n[point]){
        std::cout << n[point];
        point++;
    }
}
```

Мы в аргументах можем указать более одной переменной, и эти переменные, по сути, выстроятся в массив хранимый в `n`.
И вывод например в цикле while будет следующий:

```
while (n[point]){
    std::cout << _NAME_OF_ARG(n[point]);
    point++;
}
output: n[point]n[point]....
```

Есть ли какой либо путь сохранять названия переменных? Например передавая в `something(a,b,s,d,f,e,g)` вывод был соответствующий, а не `n[point],....`

Имхо вопрос совершенно бредовый, но имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: Может вызывать something() не напрямую, а через макрос? Который например сохранит строку аргументов и запустит something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несмотря на наличие в C++11 макросов с переменным числом аргументов, вам это не поможет - *в вашей постановке задачи*.

Судите сами - представим, что ваша функция `something(...)` скомпилирована в отдельном объектном файле. При ее вызове в стек просто вносятся разные значения, но не их имена. Как может функция в одном файле знать об *именах*, с которыми работа идет в другом файле? Метаинформация в С++ пока что не используется :) А что, если вы просто передадите константы - 1,2,3? Какие тут выводить имена?

Так что - только передавая имена вместе с аргументами. Но тогда это не будет чистый вызов функции с переменным числом аргументов - в котором, вообще говоря, типы аргументов могут быть любыми. Кстати, ваш способ работы - через `&n` - страдает, вообще говоря, непереносимостью и тем, что даже если он будет работать - то все аргументы должны быть только `int`. При работе с такими функциями следует использовать стандартные средства - `va_list` и иже с ним...

И еще - представим функцию, скажем, `f(int a, int b, int c)`. С четким количеством и именами параметров. Что будет выводиться **внутри** функции, какие имена переменных? Именно, `a`, `b`, `c` - независимо от того, что вы в нее передадите.

Так что выводить имена, не передавая их в функцию, можно только **до** вызова функции. Там, где их область видимости. А вот тут - пишите макрос с переменным числом переменных, нет вопросов:

```
#define CHECKED_CALL(...)  cout << #__VAR_ARGS__ << endl; something(__VA_ARGS__);
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
template <typename _T>
typedef struct {
    _T *pointerToVariable;
    const char *pointerToName;
} MyStructT;
typedef MyStructT<int> MyInt;

int a, b, c, d, e, f;
MyInt ma = { &a,  _NAME_OF_ARG(a) };
MyInt mb = { &b,  _NAME_OF_ARG(b) };
MyInt mc = { &c,  _NAME_OF_ARG(c) };
MyInt md = { &d,  _NAME_OF_ARG(d) };
MyInt me = { &e,  _NAME_OF_ARG(e) };
MyInt mf = { &f,  _NAME_OF_ARG(f) };

void something(const MyInt& n, ...) {
    MyInt *point = &n;
    point--;
    while (n[point]){
        std::cout << n.pointerToName;
        point++;
    }
```